# How to make Vuetify App bar scrollable horizontally

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm struggling with Vuetify App bar to make it scrollable horizontally.

Is it possible to make it scrollable or collapsable in any way?
I'm using Nuxt/Vuetify to build a platform.
[this is the image of web view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s00B7.png)

[This is the image of mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20pmi.png)

Comment: Read the documentation for toolbars: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/toolbars/#toolbars. There is a prop called collapse which might help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use v-slide-groups instead. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/slide-groups/ Please check the pen [Link](https://codepen.io/aaha/pen/OJyNQOr?editors=1010)

```
<v-app id="inspire" flex>
    <v-app-bar
      absolute
      color="cyan accent-3">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row align-center col-12">
        <div class="col-8 col-md-8">
        <v-slide-group show-arrows v-model="model">
        <v-slide-item v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }"
                    key="a">
        <v-btn icon @click="toggle">
          <v-icon>mdi-account-group</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-slide-item>
      <v-slide-item v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }" key="b">
        <v-btn icon @click="toggle">
          <v-icon>mdi-shield</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-slide-item>
      <v-slide-item v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }" key="c">
        <v-btn icon @click="toggle">
          <v-icon>mdi-school</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-slide-item>
      <v-slide-item v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }" key="d">
        <v-btn icon @click="toggle">
          <v-icon>mdi-book-open</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-slide-item>
      <v-slide-item v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }" key="e">
        <v-btn icon @click="toggle">
          <v-icon>mdi-grid</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-slide-item>
      <v-slide-item v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }" key="f">
        <v-btn icon @click="toggle">
          <v-icon>mdi-link</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-slide-item>
    </v-slide-group>
    </div>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-face</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-door</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </div>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-content>
      <v-container class="mt-10">
         <v-row>
           <v-col>
              You have clicked on {{model}} link
           </v-col>
         </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
```

Comment: This will be similar to what I want. we only need to hide the arrow button left and right. and make the slide group a little bit wider

Answer (score 3):

No option by Vuetify API. Any way you could use the idea/concept you find her (Basic CSS not related to vue/vuetify):
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_menu_horizontal_scroll.asp -or- https://iamsteve.me/blog/entry/horizontal-scrolling-responsive-menu

```
style="overflow-x:auto; white-space: nowrap;"
```

**Example:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.22/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-app-bar
                 color="deep-purple accent-4"
                 dense
                 dark
                 >
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <div style="overflow-x:auto; white-space: nowrap;">
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-domain</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-message</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-email</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-call-split</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-call-split</v-icon>
          </v-btn>        <v-btn icon>
          <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-domain</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-message</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-domain</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-message</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-btn icon>
            <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </div>

      </v-app-bar>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.2.22/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Use Media-Q if you want to disable this idea on desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want it without the scroller.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp

Comment: then I cant scroll if we hide scroll bar

Comment: This is why on desktop the scroll bar should be visible hh. For custom design scrollbar use css. For scroll by drag use js. This is the answer to your q anyway.